# How to sort list in google sheet as when the new value key in, it show in bottom list for query formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I had use multiple sheet (A, B, C) with same type of header and column except the value insert is different. The value will keep on updating and adding but when i used the query formula, it sort based on the sheet name.

```
=QUERY({A!A2:L;B!A2:L;'C'!A2:L},"Select Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col10 where Col1 is not null")
```

Can someone help me to change the query formula so that when new value insert in one of the sheet (A,B or C) it will show at bottom of the previous list and not scattered/sort according to sheet name

Sample of sheet A:
[image: Sample of sheet A]

Sample of Sheet B:
[image: SAMPLE OF SHEET B]

Sample of consolidate of sheet A & B:
[image: Sample of consolidate of sheet A & B]

Comment: Please refer to >sample sheet A<, for enquiry (abc8) was newly insert and was consolidate in >sample of consolidate<. it show in row 4 but i want the result to show that abc8 in last row of the list. Whenever there are new list, it should go to last row of the list

Comment: Welcome. Thank you for the screenshots, but they are no substitute for the actual spreadsheet. please share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding any private or confidential information) and include an example of a successful outcome. This is in your best interests - you want as many people as possible to think about your problem, but that's hard to do based on screenshots, and the risk is that they just won't bother. So, please share your a copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you need the latest entry (based on 'date' column) between all 3 sheets to be at the bottom of the combined dataset?

Comment: Hi!  If the answer below has solved your problem, please remember to Click the Tick, and accept it:  This helps anyone else with the same issue, arriving here from a Search Page, to what they need to do! :¬)

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You need to reverse the order of the sort in the `order by` method so that it descends*

#### Formula:

```
=QUERY({A!A2:L;B!A2:L;'C'!A2:L},"Select Col1,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col10 where Col1 is not null order by Col1, Col2 desc")
```

#### References:

- [QUERY function in Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)